# unable to assign array to object attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Object attribute only hold the first element of the assigned value

```
let groupedDepActivities=[]
 groupedDepActivities.push({
            id:1,
            term_activity:{
              terms:[{id:1},{from:'here'},{to:'there'},]
            }
          })
```

the `console.log()` result will be
*
term_activity:
terms: Array(1)
0:
id: "1"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
*
terms attribute only hold **the first element(id:1)** of the array not all

Comment: This worked ok for me. 
Ran this exact code in console. Inspected groupedDepActivities and drilled down terms, its an array with 3 items.

Answer (score 1):

The console's output may be truncated, but your code works as expected.

```js
let groupedDepActivities = []
groupedDepActivities.push({
  id: 1,
  term_activity: {
    terms: [{
      id: 1
    }, {
      from: 'here'
    }, {
      to: 'there'
    }, ]
  }
})

console.log(groupedDepActivities);
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "term_activity": {
      "terms": [
        {
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "from": "here"
        },
        {
          "to": "there"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

---

Were you wanting `terms` to be a single object?

```js
let groupedDepActivities = []
groupedDepActivities.push({
  id: 1,
  term_activity: {
    terms: {
      id: 1,
      from: 'here',
      to: 'there',
    }
  }
})

console.log(groupedDepActivities);
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "term_activity": {
      "terms": {
        "id": 1,
        "from": "here",
        "to": "there"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: it worked when I run on the browser'ss console, but it stores the first array element on my vuejs code? what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

you are only pushing one object, this one:

```
{
    id:1,
    term_activity:{
    terms:[{id:1},{from:'here'},{to:'there'},]
    }
}
```

Need to distiguish when you are handling an object: `{}`, from an array `[]`.
To dive deeper in your data structure for example you can do:
`console.log(groupedDepActivities=[0].term_activity.terms[0])`

Maybe its also useful to wrap your item to log in braces, as it appears as an object with names in the console, like this:
`console.log({groupedDepActivities})`

[image]

In case checking the names of the variables you log while you unfold them to  check what do they hold make you more compfortable :)